# Not all user-data steps are executed in a Terraform-managed AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform 0.12.x

I'm creating an AWS EC2 instance and want to execute shell scripts at start up so I put them in the resource's user_data_base64. I see some executed, but not all.

```
locals {
  user_data = <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
systemctl start docker.service
if [ ! -d /mnt/jenkins_master ]; then
  mkdir -p /mnt/jenkins_master
  mount /dev/xvdf /mnt/jenkins_master
fi
cp -f /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak
echo "UUID=`blkid -o value -s UUID /dev/xvdf` /mnt/jenkins_master   ext4    defaults,nofail        0       2" >> /etc/fstab
sudo su - jenkins
`aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1`
docker pull "${var.ecr_url}/${var.jenkins_image}:${var.jenkins_version}"
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v /mnt/jenkins_master/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home --name "${var.jenkins_image} ${var.ecr_url}/${var.jenkins_image}:${var.jenkins_version}"
EOF
}

resource "aws_instance" "jenkins_master_blue" {
  ...
  user_data_base64            = base64encode(local.user_data)
  ...
}
```

I don't see my echo into `/etc/fstab` nor the `docker run ...` commands executed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is couple mistake looking commands in your script

1. As I know AWS do not allow to connect to EC2 as root user directly. For example, for CentOS it will be `centos` user, or `ec2-user` for Amazon Linux. Did you switch to `root` before running this script? If no, you need to use `sudo` prefix to be able edit `fstab` and `systemctl start docker.service`.
2. You are switching to jenkins user: `sudo su - jenkins`, and after that trying to run container as `jenkins` user. Did you add `jenkins` user to `docker` group? If no, `jenkins` user do not have permissions to run containers.
3. You trying to create directory `mkdir -p /mnt/jenkins_master` as `userX` and mount `mount /dev/xvdf /mnt/jenkins_master` it as `userX`. Usually that means the only `userX` will be able to access (at least write permissions) this directory. Did you check is `jenkins` user has read/write permissions in this directory?
4. Why you switching `sudo su - jenkins` to `jenkins` user? `jenkins` has rights to control docker?
5. Don't forget to add docker service in autorun if that is not added yet. `sudo systemctl enable docker.service`.

Simple Explanation: Looks like problem reason is insufficient permissions

Comment: Ah, I didn't `sudo ...` so I don't see my entry into `/etc/fstab`. I DID however add add `jenkins` user in the `docker` group. So you partially answered my question.

Comment: Ok, I see. In this case you can ignore my question 4. Don't forget to check folder permissions after mount.

Comment: Actually, I'm able to mount the device w/o explicitly `sudo`ing so now it doesn't make sense why i can't write to /etc/fstab